# Distance from a point to a line segment in 3d (Python)

Tags: python, 3d, distance, line-segment

I am looking for Python function that would compute distance from a point in 3D (x_0,y_0,z_0) to a line *segment* defined by its endpoints (x_1,y_1,z_1) and (x_2,y_2,z_2).

I have only found solution for 2D for this problem.

There are solutions to finding a distance from a point to a line in 3d, but not to a line segment, like here:
[image: dist to segment]

(picture taken from [Calculate distance point to line segment with special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079554/calculate-distance-point-to-line-segment-with-special-cases))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortest distance between a point and a line in 3 d space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727961/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-in-3-d-space)

Comment: The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442057/calculate-the-euclidian-distance-between-an-array-of-points-to-a-line-segment-in/54442561#54442561) also works for 3D; the only change required is to take the **magnitude** of the cross-product (because it is a vector in 3D instead of a scalar).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thank you. How would I change np.maximum.reduce to fit 3D solution? It returns an error now.

Comment: For future reference always be more specific about problems than "it returns an error" or "it doesn't work". In this instance I believe changing `np.zeros(...)` to `0` would do the trick (the solution in that answer deals with an arbitrary number of tests in parallel, so `s` and `t` are **arrays** of scalars instead of single scalars).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thank you! so is it true that I also need to substitute c for np.linalg.norm(c) in return? Otherwise the return is a 3d vector.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog also, as far as I understand, the np.all loop isn't needed for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is adapted from here:
[Calculate the euclidian distance between an array of points to a line segment in Python without for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442057/calculate-the-euclidian-distance-between-an-array-of-points-to-a-line-segment-in/54442561#54442561).

Function `lineseg_dist` returns the distance the distance from point p to line segment [a,b]. `p`, `a` and `b` are np.arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def lineseg_dist(p, a, b):

    # normalized tangent vector
    d = np.divide(b - a, np.linalg.norm(b - a))

    # signed parallel distance components
    s = np.dot(a - p, d)
    t = np.dot(p - b, d)

    # clamped parallel distance
    h = np.maximum.reduce([s, t, 0])

    # perpendicular distance component
    c = np.cross(p - a, d)

    return np.hypot(h, np.linalg.norm(c))
```

Comment: Beware that `p, a, b` are *arrays of arrays* (i.e. arrays of points). For your problem you probably want to work with a single set of points, in which case `s` and `t` will be scalars - thus `np.zeros(len(p))` will need to be placed with `0`. And yes if you can guarantee that `a` is never equal to `b` then the "`np.all`" check is unnecessary

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yeah, forgot to make that edit about s and t. 

also, np.all as far as I understood checks if a and b are along the same axis, I am not sure if you need to substitute for np.array_equal